# Error in seq2seq translation when passing predicted output to rnn due to input shape not always being the same

Tags: python, rnn, language-model, sequence-to-sequence, spacy

I'm working on a language translator and I'm getting an error I'm unsure about.

During the decoding process when using argmax on the predicted output I am sometimes getting an RuntimeError `RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 4`

On the iterations that work the `input` has a shape of `torch.Size([64])`
but some iterations the input

This is my encoder and decoder models.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers, p):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size
        self.mnum_layers=num_layers

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, embedding_size)
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout=p)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x shape: (seq_length, N)

        embedding=self.dropout(self.embedding(x))
        # embedding shape: (seq_len, N, embedding_size)

        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedding)

        return hidden, cell

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers, p):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size
        self.num_layers=num_layers

        self.dropout=nn.Dropout(p)
        self.embedding=nn.Embedding(input_size, embedding_size)
        self.rnn=nn.LSTM(embedding_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout=p)
        self.fc=nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    
    def forward(self, x, hidden, cell):
        x = x.unsqueeze(0)
        # x shape:(1, N)

        embedding=self.dropout(self.embedding(x))
        # embedding shape: (1, N, embedding_size)

        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedding, (hidden, cell))

        prediction=self.fc(outputs)
        # prediction shape: (1, N, vocab_len)

        prediction.unsqueeze(0)

        return prediction, hidden, cell
```

This is the Seq2seq model.

```
class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(Seq2Seq, self).__init__()
        self.encoder=encoder
        self.decoder=decoder

    def forward(self, source, target, teacher_force_ratio=0.7):
        batch_size = source.shape[1]
        target_len = target.shape[0]
        target_vocab_size = len(english.vocab)

        outputs = torch.zeros(target_len, batch_size, target_vocab_size).to(device)

        hidden, cell = self.encoder(source)

        # get start token
        input = target[0]

        for t in range(1, target_len):
            teacher_force = random.random() < teacher_force_ratio
            print('teacher force')
            print(teacher_force)
            print('input shape')
            print(input.shape)

            output, hidden, cell = self.decoder(input, hidden, cell)
            print('output shape')
            print(output.shape)

            outputs[t] = output
        
            best_guess = output.argmax(1)
            # best guess shape:(N, eng_vocab_size)
            print('best guess shape')
            print(best_guess.shape)

            print('target[t] shape')
            print(target[t].shape)
            print()

            input = target[t] if teacher_force else best_guess

        return outputs
```

This is what the seq2seq print statements say

```
teach force
True
input shape
torch.Size([64])
output shape
torch.Size([1, 64, 5893])
best guess shape
torch.Size([1, 5893])
target[t]
torch.Size([64])

...

teach force
False
input shape
torch.Size([64])
output shape
torch.Size([1, 64, 5893])
best guess shape
torch.Size([1, 5893])
target[t]
torch.Size([64])

teach force
True
input shape
torch.Size([1, 5893])
```

I'm using Spacy and the `de_core_news_sm` to `en_core_web_sm` datasets using Mutli30k to split the data into training, validation and test datasets.

```
spacy_german = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")
spacy_english = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def tokenizer_german(text):
    return [token.text for token in spacy_german.tokenizer(text)]

def tokenizer_english(text):
    return [token.text for token in spacy_english.tokenizer(text)]

german = Field(tokenize=tokenizer_german, lower=True,
                init_token='<sos>', eos_token='<eos>')

english = Field(tokenize=tokenizer_english, lower=True,
                init_token='<sos>', eos_token='<eos>')

train_data, validation_data, test_data=Multi30k.splits(exts=('.de', '.en'),
                                                        fields=(german, english))

german.build_vocab(train_data, max_size=10000, min_freq=2)
english.build_vocab(train_data, max_size=10000, min_freq=2)
```

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "language_translator.py", line 194, in <module>
    output = model(input_data, target)
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "language_translator.py", line 113, in forward
    output, hidden, cell = self.decoder(input, hidden, cell)
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "language_translator.py", line 78, in forward
    outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(embedding, (hidden, cell))
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 579, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 530, in check_forward_args
    self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
  File "/Users/yeliab/anaconda3/envs/xnap-example/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 174, in check_input
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 4
```

I'm really unsure why the input shape is sometimes different.